# Authentication for Git Daemon and Windows

Tags: windows, git

I'm using Windows machines as clients and server; I would like to use git daemon to deploy, but it looks like it doesn't support authentication. I'd prefer not to use SSH, but would Gitolite be the only good option? Or are there others that work well with Windows?

Or is there a better way to deploy and push to production with Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Git *can* be used for deployment, I usually recommend using something that's designed for it instead.

On Windows, [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/overview) is a good option. Alternatively, most CI tools can do deployment. Check out [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) for something open source, or [Travis](https://travis-ci.org) for something more "cloudy". Depending in your needs, all of these can be free to use.

All of these can be *triggered by* `git push`, but this isn't the same as using Git for deployment.